# Modelling results of an election in Django

Tags: python, django, web, django-models

I'm trying to figure out how to model the an election in Django. I have a model `Candidate`. There have to be exactly two candidates, so the definition is as follows:

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.surname
    def clean(self):
        if (len(Candidate.objects.all()) > 1):
            raise ValidationError(
                "There are two candidates already"
            )
```

And I want to have a model `CountyResult`, with the following fields: county (foreign), number of residents, number of residents eligible for voting etc. and with the final results of the election in this county.

I would like to be able to insert the election results in the `admin` site.

And my question is: how can I implement the `Candidate -> votes` mapping inside the `CountyResult` model? I was thinking about simply storing values `first_candidate_votes, second_candidate_votes`, but that's obviously not a great solution, since I would like to be able to remove a candidate.

I was also thinking about adding a `SingleResult` model with a foreign key `candidate` and somehow 'put it' inside the `CountyResult` class, but there is no such thing as a two-to-one relation in Django

I would appreciate any hints. I'm new to Django, so it's almost certain that the solution is rather easy and technical

Comment: You might want to read up on related managers in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it makes most sense to me to have 3 models: Candidate, County, and Results. County would have the county, residents, and eligible voters fields. Results will have foreign keys to Candidate and County and then the vote count field (either total or two fields if you want to keep the vote tally separate).

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class County(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    population = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)
    eligible_voters = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)

class Result(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) # you could give an election a name I suppose, i.e. 2016 primary
    county = models.ForeignKey('County',)
    winner = models.ForeignKey('Candidate',)
    loser = models.ForeignKey('Candidate',)
    total_votes = models.IntegerField(max_length=50) # break this out into other fields if you want more detail
```

Comment: So you're suggesting that every County references to two Results?